# Why do we reproduce?

Tags: consciousness, life

Why do we (including other living organisms) reproduce? Why is it necessary that our race keeps flourishing and multiplying? I couldn't find any useful articles on google except for some yahoo and wiki answers which I don't like much. I would like if someone could suggest me some books or redirect me to some useful articles.
Also,
this might sound more of a question pertaining to biology but do unicellular organisms have mind and feelings? Just in case if they don't, then whats the motivation behind their reproduction?

Comment: Because our ancestors who didn't reproduce didn't have any children.

Comment: This is patently an evolutionary biology question...

Comment: yes.. this question is very biology oriented. It could be improved, giving it a focus towards human beings as I did in my answer, but even so I'm not sure if it would be a philosophical problem (rather than psychological, or sociological); it would require some radical reshaping, definitely.

Answer (score 5):

> Why do we (including other living organisms) reproduce?

I don't think that "why" is a useful question here- it is akin to asking why we exist in time and space.  In our universe, living organisms reproduce.  That's simply a naked fact.

> Why is it necessary that our race keeps flourishing and multiplying?

It is not necessary; in fact, it's highly contingent.  Just ask the dinosaurs.

> Also, this might sound more of a question pertaining to biology but do unicellular organisms have mind and feelings?

I don't think that anyone proposes that unicellular organisms are sentient; in fact, very few would suggest that plants are sentient.

> Just in case if they don't, then whats the motivation behind their reproduction?

There is no motivation involved.  What is a rock's motivation for rolling downhill?  What is an apple's motivation for falling off of a tree?  There are causes, and there are effects, but there is no evidence for anything resembling "will" involved.

Answer (score 1):

Since living individuals often die, only those that reproduce may survive (as a species). Humans are still here, so it is necessary that humans as a species reproduce.

The same argument applies to other living beings.

For resources, look up something related to evolution. I can't really recommend anything specific, but maybe start at the Wikipedia article and especially references therein. Or look at the course books of the relevant courses in some university.

Answer (score 1):

For "why reproduction happens", and all the types of reproduction, you should take a look at evolutionist theory (specially, the differences between sexual and assexual reproduction may be of interest).
Now... as of humans, it is an interesting question, as there's nothing "natural" in the way humans deal with sexuality.
A classic on this is Freud's "Three essays on sexuality", where he delves in the question of what is normal and what is a deviation in human sex life. If sex aims at reproduction, every activity that doesn't fulfill this (masturbation, homossexuality, and even kissing) should be considered a deviation, so he ends up with the idea that there's no normality in human sexuality. In the end, he concludes that, for humans, sex as reproduction needs to be a cultural (moral) value.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we (including other living organisms) reproduce?

We reproduce because it was a successful way through evolution for living species to succeed. Of course, you could ask "why did the first living cell reproduced itself". Many believe (it is still not clearly demonstrated) that the reproduction of the first cell was simply a chemical reaction.

> Why is it necessary that our race keeps flourishing and multiplying?

It is not. However, our "base code" tell us to keep multiplying. Moreover, we could even say that we are to a point where humanity should ask itself to stop or slow reproduction because more human means more destruction of our environment. We are the first known race that might override its genetic behavior with pure intelligence and logic.

> Do unicellular organisms have mind and feelings?

Feeling require an evolved brain. Unicellular organisms obviously don't have brain. Therefore, they can't have feeling.